# TabBarView with multiple tabs causing every screen to be created in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

Tab1 jumping to tab2, tab2 screen invokes initState() -> tab1 screen invokes dispose(). New screen created, unselected screen got disposed. Everything in order and works perfectly.

But, things gets a bit weird when it comes to 3 tabs: tab1, tab2, tab3. The first scenario works fine just as above.

On tab1 then select tab2, tab2 screen invokes initState() -> tab1 screen invokes dispose(). When on tab2 then select tab3, tab3 screen invokes initState() -> tab2 screen invokes dispose()
But the scenario below becomes quite confusing
2. On tab1 then select tab3, tab1 screen invokes initState() and dispose() -> tab2 screen invokes initState() -> tab3 screen invokes initState() -> tab1 screen invokes dispose() -> tab2 screen invokes dispose()

There are 2 main concerns with the above scenario when jumping from tab1 to tab3:

tab1 invokes the full cycles methods, initState() and dispose(), before it jumps to tab3 which is abnormal to the first scenario. This is will cause problem if I have a platform call placed inside initState() which will get triggered again.
tab2 screen is created when it is not even selected. That is also a problem cause if I have some work placed in initState(), it will also gets triggered unexpectedly.
Im not sure if this is intended but it is clearly not right to me. Maybe it is just me doing something wrong. I have tried to google about this issue but couldn't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

In a simple language, On just little swipe of tab it calls init method of next tab. It should call init method if I go to another tab. But without changing tab it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the state of your screen in the `TabBarView`,then you can use the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in your State class.

After that, you have to override the `wantKeepAlive` method and `return true`.

For an example:

```js
class _DemoScreenState extends State<DemoScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<DemoScreen>{

...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    // You have to call this method
    super.build(context); 

    /// your widget will be here
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;//you have to set it true

}
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday. But It is not working